# Default values for percent type custom setting field incorrect when clicking new in manage

Tags: customsetting

I have a custom setting with a percent type field, which has a default value set (0.25).

In apex, if there is no Custom setting for the user, getInstance gets back the correct default value of 25%.

```
Custom_Settings__c setting = Custom_Settings__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getUserId());
System.debug(setting.Percent_Field__c);
```

But if I click manage in the front end and click new - an incorrect value is shown (0.25). Does anyone know why this is the case?

Thanks

**Edit** - To be clear I am just talking about the standard Salesforce CRUD screen for the custom setting (via the manage button)

[image: Custom Setting CRUD screen]

Comment: Can you post your frontend code? Probably it's because you are not using output fields but just outputting the value directly

Comment: This also seems to differ to the behaviour in other parts of the system. If I add a custom percent field to Account and set default value as 0.25. When I click new the correct 25% value is shown